# Bayesian testing that one parameter is larger than another

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, posterior

In a Bayesian setting and given data $D$ I want to test the hypothesis that $$H_0: \theta_2 \le \theta_1$$ against alternative $H_1: \theta_2 > \theta_1$.  Assume I can only sample from the posterior distributions, e.g. with MCMC. In particular I can sample from the posteriors $p(\theta_2|D)$ and $p(\theta_1|D)$.

In a simple situation we could think of the $\theta$ as group means of two independent samples $D_1$ and $D_2$. But in my particular case $\theta$ are different functions $f$ and $g$ applied on partly the same variables, so $\theta_1 = f(Y)$ and $\theta_2 = g(X,Y)$. So I suppose $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are correlated.

Is there a way to evaluate the probabilitiy the hypotheses are true using just the posterior samples?

Comment: When you say you can sample from the marginal posteriors, does it mean you can _only_ do that? (sounds strange) There is no way you could get a joint sample from $p(\theta_1, \theta_2 | D)$? Gibbs or slice sampling would work too, it doesn't mean that you have to sample both variables simultaneously in a single step, as long as the Markov chain samples from the joint posterior.

Comment: @lacerbi Yes I know only how to do that. The situation is as follows. Theta is a proportion. The posterior of $\theta_1$ is beta and has the known analytical solution from binomial-beta conjugacy. The posterior of $\theta_2$ can be sampled from but is not known analytically. $\theta_2$ is a model based estimator of the proportion that uses more information (that is, a more complex model than the binomial-beta model of $\theta_1$). I do not know how to sample jointly under this circumstance.

Comment: I think the short answer is "no you can't do what you want" and the long answer is "maybe you can but you haven't told us enough yet." Is this one model or two? Do $X$ and $Y$ refer to datasets? Do $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ have the same meaning? If you spell out your setup more clearly, someone might be able to provide more advice.